# Windows 7, Windows 8 entries missing after reinstalling grub

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I originally had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. After I installed Windows preview on a logical partition, the Windows boot loader showed only Windows 7 and Windows 8, there was no option to start Ubuntu, so I reinstalled GRUB (following [this procedure](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-Ubuntu-live-cd/) but now GRUB shows only Ubuntu 12.04.

I ran the boot info script, and this is the RESULTS.txt i got

---

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos3)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grldr /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /grldr

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda3 
                       and looks at sector 1920334440 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       for (,msdos3)/boot/grub on this drive.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda7 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         962,562,048 1,910,774,879   948,212,832   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3       1,910,774,880 1,953,519,119    42,744,240  83 Linux
/dev/sda4             206,910   962,554,319   962,347,410   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5             206,912   102,402,047   102,195,136   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         102,402,111   942,081,839   839,679,729   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda7         942,081,903   962,554,319    20,472,417   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        2AF85FE4F85FAD37                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        C46A69CD6A69BCB4                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537   ext4       
/dev/sda5        B66E58FA6E58B4B9                       ntfs       
/dev/sda6        D4A667A2A66783B8                       ntfs       
/dev/sda7        C05AB0F95AB0ED72                       ntfs       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda3        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda6        /media/D4A667A2A66783B8  fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7        /media/C05AB0F95AB0ED72  fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)


========================== sda1/grldr embedded menu: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda3/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=70fc8e20-b69b-47cd-98cf-9c9b0b30e537 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                boot/grub/core.img                             1
               =                boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae           2
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae           2
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae              1
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae              1
               =                initrd.img                                     2
               =                initrd.img.old                                 2
               =                vmlinuz                                        1
               =                vmlinuz.old                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  00 26 01 26 02 26 03 26  04 26 05 26 06 26 07 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000010  08 26 09 26 0a 26 0b 26  0c 26 0d 26 0e 26 0f 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000020  10 26 11 26 12 26 13 26  14 26 15 26 16 26 17 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000030  18 26 19 26 1a 26 1b 26  1c 26 1d 26 1e 26 1f 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000040  20 26 21 26 22 26 23 26  24 26 25 26 26 26 27 26  | &!&"&#&$&%&&&'&|
00000050  28 26 29 26 2a 26 2b 26  2c 26 2d 26 2e 26 2f 26  |(&)&*&+&,&-&.&/&|
00000060  30 26 31 26 32 26 33 26  34 26 35 26 36 26 37 26  |0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&|
00000070  38 26 39 26 3a 26 3b 26  3c 26 3d 26 3e 26 3f 26  |8&9&:&;&<&=&>&?&|
00000080  40 26 41 26 42 26 43 26  44 26 45 26 46 26 47 26  |@&A&B&C&D&E&F&G&|
00000090  48 26 49 26 4a 26 4b 26  4c 26 4d 26 4e 26 4f 26  |H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&|
000000a0  50 26 51 26 52 26 53 26  54 26 55 26 56 26 57 26  |P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&|
000000b0  58 26 59 26 5a 26 5b 26  5c 26 5d 26 5e 26 5f 26  |X&Y&Z&[&\&]&^&_&|
000000c0  60 26 61 26 62 26 63 26  64 26 65 26 66 26 67 26  |`&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&|
000000d0  68 26 69 26 6a 26 6b 26  6c 26 6d 26 6e 26 6f 26  |h&i&j&k&l&m&n&o&|
000000e0  70 26 71 26 72 26 73 26  74 26 75 26 76 26 77 26  |p&q&r&s&t&u&v&w&|
000000f0  78 26 79 26 7a 26 7b 26  7c 26 7d 26 7e 26 7f 26  |x&y&z&{&|&}&~&.&|
00000100  80 26 81 26 82 26 83 26  84 26 85 26 86 26 87 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000110  88 26 89 26 8a 26 8b 26  8c 26 8d 26 8e 26 8f 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000120  90 26 91 26 92 26 93 26  94 26 95 26 96 26 97 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000130  98 26 99 26 9a 26 9b 26  9c 26 9d 26 9e 26 9f 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000140  a0 26 a1 26 a2 26 a3 26  a4 26 a5 26 a6 26 a7 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000150  a8 26 a9 26 aa 26 ab 26  ac 26 ad 26 ae 26 af 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000160  b0 26 b1 26 b2 26 b3 26  b4 26 b5 26 b6 26 b7 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000170  b8 26 b9 26 ba 26 bb 26  bc 26 bd 26 be 26 bf 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000180  c0 26 c1 26 c2 26 c3 26  c4 26 c5 26 c6 26 c7 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
00000190  c8 26 c9 26 ca 26 cb 26  cc 26 cd 26 ce 26 cf 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
000001a0  d0 26 d1 26 d2 26 d3 26  d4 26 d5 26 d6 26 d7 26  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&|
000001b0  d8 26 d9 26 da 26 db 26  dc 26 dd 26 de 26 00 a4  |.&.&.&.&.&.&.&..|
000001c0  15 0d 07 ef ff ff 02 00  00 00 c0 5f 17 06 00 ef  |..........._....|
000001d0  ff ff 05 ef ff ff c2 5f  17 06 30 7f 0c 32 00 00  |......._..0..2..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

Comment: try `sudo update-grub` from a terminal, after logging in to your installation on disk. **Not from a live cd**

Comment: and if the `update-grub` didnt work try this `sudo apt-get install os-prober` then `sudo os-prober`

Comment: @Mahesh thanks.. it worked :) now i have a single option for windows8 in grub. When i enter it i am taken to the windows boot loader screen with options to boot windows7, windows8

Comment: @krzna Since it solved your problem, I've posted it as an answer. you may mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your can log in to your installed Ubuntu system, open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub` to let GRUB update its entries.